# Which jars do I need to use hibernate 3.5 and hibernate-validator? I'm use Websphere 8.0

Tags: java, hibernate

I have searched everywhere for a list of jars necessary and they don't seem to be available all in one bundle as they are in 4.x.  This is my first go at setting it up. 
Also, does it matter which version of hibernate validator I use if I'm using Hibernate 3.5?
I would like to use 4.x, but I cannot solve this problem:

[Unexpected UnsupportedOperationException on Hibernate validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388069/unexpected-unsupportedoperationexception-on-hibernate-validation-failure/13412563#comment18339301_13412563)

Comment: Also, for any bundle in the Hibernate proyects, [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/)  is the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using maven for building, you should download the Hibernate bundle from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.5.5-Final/). It contains all the dependencies you need.

Also, I have been using Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final with Hibernate 3.5.6 final so I think there should be no problem.

You can download the Hibernate Validator bundle at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/) too.

Comment: Thanks.  I have both of these and I'm still experiencing problems. Don't you need the hibernate-entitymanager jar?  Would you mind posting you DAO code or a snippet so I can see how you're doing the persist?  I'm using the entityManager to do the persist maybe this is wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  But that maybe not be necessary.  I'm basically wondering if you're using the entityManager as I am.  You can see my DAO if you follow the link in my question.

Comment: Oh well, I am not using JPA, just plain Hibernate, if you want to see the code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/ElderMael/jgtjo/src/33c816b4e03e/schedule-parent?at=master) but I used hibernate validator with JSF not in my Entities.

Comment: Check the pom.xml to see the dependencies used.